# Can't access Google Cloud Compute Instance External IP (boot fedora35)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a `nodejs app` running inside it a `vm instance`.
I created a `firewall rule` **opening port tcp:5000**.
It works locally (inside vm) and I am able to verify the connection via

```
sudo wget http://localhost:5000
```

this gives `status 200` ok.

when I replace the `localhost` with the **vm external Ip address** I get a connection time out.
[image]
[image]

I have tried most things I could get on the internet but now I am tired. Its my first time interacting with gcp so I guess it's expected.

Comment: I'd look closely at the NodeJS app.  When an app listens for incoming connections, depending on how it is coded, it can choose to listen on only a subset of network interfaces.  Run "netstat -an" on the Compute Engine and see what is listening on port 5000.  If its says 127.0.0.1 then thats the problem.  You should want 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Network tags on the VM instance do not match your firewall rule `inventory-controller-port`.  The Compute Engine Instance has these network tags `http-server`, `https-server`. To resolve this issue, these are your options.

1. Update the Firewall rule `inventory-controller-port` and add these network tags  `http-server`, `https-server`. For more information, check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#updating_firewall_rules) about updating firewall rules.
2. Add additional network tags that you added on the Firewall rule `inventory-controller-port` on your existing VM. To know more check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) about Adding tags to an existing VM.